# Nested mapping with entityFramework Automapper .Net Core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, automapper, dto

Here is my query with Entity Framework :

```
var transportlist = await _context.Set<Transport>()
       .Include(transport => transport.TransportState)
       .Select(transport =>
           new
           {
               Transport = _mapper.Map<TransportDto>(transport),
               TransportState = _mapper.Map<TransportStateForTransportDto>(transport.TransportState),
           }
        )
        .Take(limitNumber)
        .ToListAsync();

 return transportlist;
```

Here is my TransportDto :

```
public class TransportDto
{
    public int TransportId { get; set; }
    public TransportStateForTransportDto TransportState { get; set; }
    public bool Locked { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my TransportStateForTransportDto :

```
public class TransportStateForTransportDto
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to have something like that as result :

```
[
    {
        "transportId": 123456,
        "transportState" : {
            "Label": "Deleted"
        },
        "locked" : false
    }
]
```

But, I have this one (and it is a bit logical...) :

```
[
    {
        "transport": {
            "transportId": 123456,
            "transportState" : {
                "Label": "Deleted"
             },
             "locked" : false
        },
        "transportstate": {
            "Label": "Deleted"
        }           
    }
]
```

I thought about doing like this :

```
var transportlist = await _context.Set<Transport>()
       .Include(transport => transport.TransportState)
       .Select(transport =>
           new
           {
               _mapper.Map<TransportDto>(transport),
           }
        )
        .Take(limitNumber)
        .ToListAsync();

 return transportlist;
```

But, if I do, the property transportstate in JSON equals NULL.

So I am trying to do nested mapping where Transport should be mapped with its object properties mapped too. Note that all the properties have exactly the same name.

I wrote a Profile for mapping which is :

```
public class TransportsProfile : Profile
    {
        public TransportsProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<TransportState, TransportStateForTransportDto>();
            CreateMap<Transport, TransportDto>();
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: This is not exactly what i'm expecting for... Indeed, in their example you won't get the JSON format I asked for. Moreover, I don't want to assign fields manually but I want to map the dto globally in order to have more flexible code. How could I map into the mapping?

Comment: You've completely misunderstood. Take the time and go through the docs and some examples.

Comment: It's pretty dangerous to map directly in a EF call, because [it's possible to get very deep calls (back to EF) for navigation properties](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#preventing-lazy-loading-select-n-1-problems) and/or get into infinite loops via circular recursion.  I'd highly recommend turning off lazy loading (if you haven't already) and then mapping your objects outside the EF calls.

Comment: Lazy loading is disabled. Then do you think I should first making my query. Then, use the obtained list to map it to my Dto schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Automapper 8 or above you should leverage `ProjectTo` rather than `Map` to translate entities into DTOs.

```
var transportlist = await _context.Set<Transport>()
    .ProjectTo<TransportDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .Take(limitNumber)
    .ToListAsync();
```

*Edit: had _mapper.Configuration above, looks like the config is provided by ConfigurationProvider.*

Given that your TransportDTO contains a reference to the related TransportState DTO, automapper should be able to tell EF exactly what fields are needed from the related entities to ensure that they are loaded properly. The issue with `Map` is that this is really geared towards loaded objects, not expressions that EF could otherwise turn into SQL.

With using `Take` you should also have an Order By clause to ensure the items returned are predictable when more than that limit are present.

Like using `Select` for projection, there is no need to eager load any of the related details or disable lazy loading. EF will simply compose a query to pull the required fields provided your DTOs are purely simple data containers and don't contain references to entities within them.

Comment: It works. This is perfect. Thank you. One more question is just that you are using _mapper.Configuration. Visual studio only propose _mapper.ConfigurationProvider, which I'm using anyway.

Comment: Yes, that would be the one, I generally pull my answers from memory if I'm not on my workstation with a suitable example handy. :)